# React Native Onesignal - User status unsubscribed after a notification is sent

Tags: react-native, onesignal

Whenever a notification is sent to a specific player id, the user with that player id is unsubscribed. The status before sending the notification was subscribed in OneSignal dashboard. No notification is received on the device. All corresponding notifications sent from REST API returns the response as error :

```
{ id: '',
recipients: 0,
errors:
{ invalid_player_ids: [ 'example_player_id' ] } }
```

**Environment**

> OneSignal SDK - "react-native-onesignal": "^3.3.2" React Native
>   Version - "react-native": "^0.60.4",

Comment: Show us the code that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue, kindly check if your project is using both GCM and FCM both. I had react-native-push-notifications library which was using GCM while OneSignal was using FCM. Removing this conflict solved the issue.